# Rails partial not refreshing with create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I realize there are dozens of similar questions here on this topic, I have looked through many of them and tried to duplicate the solutions and nothing has worked for me.

I have a list of tasks displayed in the index view as a partial, when the user adds a task I would like list to show the newest task (as well as all the others already there).

Here is the create controller:

```
def create
    @task = current_user.tasks.build(task_params)

    if @task.save
      flash[:success] = "Task added"
      respond_to do |format|
          format.js
        end

    else
      flash[:error] = "Task not added"
      render 'new'
    end
```

The _new partial:

```
<%= form_for(@task, method: :post, remote: true) do |f| %>
<%= f.label :comments %>
<%= f.text_field :comments, id: "task-comments" %>
<%= f.submit "Insert" %>
<% end %>
```

Index.html.erb

```
<div id="new-task-form">
  <%= render 'new'  %>
</div>
<div id="current-tasks">
  <%= render partial: 'show_list', locals: {tasks: @tasks} %>
</div>
```

create.js.erb

```
    console.log("create.js.erb called");
document.getElementById("task-comments").value = "";
document.getElementById("current-tasks").html('<%= j(render partial: "show_list") %>');
```

I have been able to get the console to log the message and even been able to clear the input box but the partial does not render, I have tried this in a few different ways and the script always seems to stop executing when it gets to the escape javascript line.

There are no JS errors, as stated above, the console logs the message when the "submit" button is pressed.  There is a warning `[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 114ms` but I don't think that is relevant to this issue.

Here is the partial that I am trying to render _show_list.html.erb

```
<% unless @tasks.nil? %>
<ul>
<% tasks.each do |tsk| %>
<li><%= tsk.comments %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
<% end %>
```

Comment: can you open the browser console to see if there are js errors? and please add the html.erb where you have the container

Comment: No errors, I've added the _show_list partial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def create
    @task = current_user.tasks.build(task_params)

    if @task.save
      flash[:success] = "Task added"
      #respond_to do |format|
          #format.js
      #end

    else
      flash[:error] = "Task not added"
      render 'new'
    end
end
```

It's always good practice to use local variable in partial

1) => Index.html.erb

```
<div id="new-task-form">
  <%= render 'new'  %>
</div>
<div id="current-tasks">
  <%= render partial: 'show_list', locals: {tasks: @tasks} %>
</div>
```

2) => If you are using jquery (create.js.erb)

```
console.log("create.js.erb called");
$("#task-comments").val('');
$("#current-tasks").html('<%= j render "show_list", tasks: @tasks) %>');
```

3) => _show_list.html.erb(Use `tasks` instead of `@tasks`)

```
<% unless tasks.blank? %>
  <ul>
    <% tasks.each do |tsk| %>
      <li><%= tsk.comments %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Wow, this is awesome, thank you so much!  I'm believe that removing the `respond_to` statement is what did it but I don't know why, I don't understand how it knows to call the create.js.erb without that statement...

Comment: @tfantina Once you will have a look at server logs, `ajax request` is served as `js request` instead of `html request` so, rails is smart enough to render it on `create.js.erb` if request is js request . anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ok you have some problem here with your validation on the `show_list` partial.
you have this line

```
<% unless @tasks.nil? %>
```

try to use something more readable like

```
<% if @tasks.present? %>
```

and on your controller create action, you don't fill the @tasks variable, so that's the problem in reality, add on you controller the load for all the tasks after saving the new one.

```
if @task.save
  @tasks = Task.all
  flash[:success] = "Task added"
```

and that will make it work, but I recommend to load just the created one and add just one column to the table and not update the complete list again if you have all the others on the client already.

Comment: Thanks for that, I've changed the show_list partial to be more readable.  Also added the `@tasks = Task.all` or specifically `@tasks = Task.where(user_id: current_user.id)`  and everything renders properly according to the logs:  transaction commits and renders both create.js.erb and _show_list.html.erb but nothing on the page changes.

Comment: Awesome, be aware of loading all the notes, it's better to load just the created one and add it to the existing list on client.

Comment: Sorry I may not have made that clear, although according to the server log create.js and _show_list.html are rendering nothing changes, so effectively the new task is not added.  I briefly played around with appending the task unto the list which you point out is best practice but I also had no luck with that.